# $http.post is working but $http.put is not working

Tags: angularjs, http, httprequest, put, slim

I recently created a CRUD application using AngularJS and Slim PHP Rest services. This simple application works just fine on my local server, but when I uploaded the application to a server at iPage.com, item edits are no longer working.

I find that although POST requests properly contain my payload in the request body, Slim seems  unable to extract anything from the request bodies of any PUT requests.

I can provide whatever additional details, but does anyone have any idea why $http.post would continue working properly while $http.put would begin to fail? I have an idea that it might have something to do with my server configuration, but Im not sure where to start looking.

Thanks!!

Comment: The put method could be disabled in the remote server. Take a look at the server OPTIONS configuration.

Comment: Do you have any hints about where in an apache server configuration such a configuration might exist?

Comment: This was just a matter of my server's security.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this at your `SLIM's` index file:

```
Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->put('api url', function() use ($app) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    // Rest of the PUT code...
});
```